# First undo the denominator doesn't work for $s - \frac{3s}{8}=\frac{5}{6}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve $s - \frac{3s}{8}=\frac{5}{6}$, which is probably basic for you all, but I am kinda stuck. I know I can solve this by doing the following steps:

$s - \frac{3s}{8}=\frac{5}{6}$

$s - \frac{3}{8} \cdot s=\frac{5}{6}$

$s(1 - \frac{3}{8}) =\frac{5}{6}$

$s(\frac{5}{8}) =\frac{5}{6}$

$s =\frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{8}{5} = \frac{4}{3}$

But I cannot get my head around it why I cannot find a solution by just first multiplying 8 by its reciprocal. I keep getting stuck at

$s - \frac{3s}{8} =\frac{5}{6}$

$s - \frac{3s}{8} \cdot 8 =\frac{5}{6} \cdot 8$

$s - 3s =\frac{40}{6}$

So I know my previous method works, but I want to understand why this way, by first multiplying does not work. Am I doing some step just wrong or trying the impossible.

Comment: can you elaborate on what exactly confuses you? The solution you posted is correct, what step you have doubts about?

Comment: I have updated my question. I just wanted to show I know how to get to the solution in some way. But I want to know why first canceling the reciprocal out doesn't work for me. I just cannot get my head around it why it is logical it doesn't work or if I am just doing something wrong

Comment: You just forgot to multiply $s$ by 8, otherwise that's a correct approach as well Should be $8s-3s$

Comment: Thanks, I will try to remember that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$s - \frac{3s}{8}=\frac{5}{6}$

*Multiply through by $8$:

$\color{red}8s - {3} s=8\times\frac{5}{6}$

$5s =\frac{40}{6}$

$s =\frac{8}{6}=\frac 4 3$

---

*Remember to multiply both $s$ and $\frac {3s} 8$ by $8$;

it appears  that you forgot to multiply $s$ by 8 too.

Comment: Thank you! The answer I was looking for. Now it makes more sense indeed, cool :)